# jQuery 3.0 Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari desktop version compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, compatibility

Currently I'm using jQuery 1.8.1. I'm going to upgrade to 3.0 for security reasons. When I see the [Browser support section](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#browser-support), it's saying:

> Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari: Current and Current - 1

But I'm not sure what it means.

1. ex. Google chrome : 65.0.3325.181 jquery 3.0 compatible to 64.0.x but not previous versions?
2. `current` means the time when jQuery 3.0 released?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, means that they *guarantee* compatibility for the `Current` and the `Current - 1` versions **of browsers**, not of jQuery.

This does not imply that jQuery won't work on previous versions of all browsers, just that every bug or problem in previous browsers version won't be fixed, unless it happens also in current browsers version.

Actually, most of jQuery code works flawlessly in older browsers.

It's worth pointing that nowadays every browser in every platform (Windows, Mac, Linux, Android...) comes with automatic updates, so old browsers are increasingly uncommon.